# Bi-directional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got two models with simple associations

```
class Door 
  belongs_to :main_room, class_name: 'Room', inverse_of: :door
end 

####

class Room
  has_one :door, foreing_key: :main_room_id
end
```

Could you please tell me why

```
door.build_main_room.door
```

returns nil?

UPD:

```
door.build_main_room 
# =>  #<Room id: nil>
```

**UPD2:** 
Oh, guys, it is totaly my mistake. Associations are correct, but in Room class method `door` is defined and it returns nil. Without it everything works fine.

Comment: can u post results of door.buil_main_room

Comment: @Amar yep, here you are.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
door.build_main_room.door
```

will return nil, because you have not saved your built object. To save it you need to use

```
door.save
```

if it saves successfully then you only you can access like

```
door.main_room.door
```

Comment: IIRC `:inverse_of` option adds door object to built room object. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, it only define name for association and accordingly use primary key on build i.e. it updates main_room_id